# How do I send a push notification from SDK/framework to parent app?

Tags: php, server, push-notification, notifications, sdk

I have developed a framework for both iOS and Android.

This framework needs to send a push notification to users once there is an update, which would be once a day.

How do I manage the notifications from my framework? It will require the parent app to send out the notification to the end user.

We are using PHP, swift and java

The notifications are send in the app version but it is not showing in the framework

```
// push notification
        if($ref->endpoint_arn)
        {
            $helper->push(null, $ref->endpoint_arn, __('push.new-live', ['user' => $player->username]));
        }
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }

    return response()->json(['errors' => [__('api.error-referral-code-applied')]], 400);
```

The expectation is that the push notification would send to the end user when it is generated on the back end. There are no error messages, just the notification is not sending

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be an Android or iOS Problem, more like a php and Server Problem.

for Messaging you should read the firebase Messaging Service documentation on how to send push notifications.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages

Comment: yes the code I posted is PHP code. I am trying to figure out how to send the notificaiton from the server to the parent app and how that should be managed? thanks for the link